# ¿Como puedo modificar el siguiente js para que descargue la tabla html como un Excel sin que me reemplaze caracteres como la ñ?

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen día, tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy usando una función en javascript la cual toma los datos de una tabla html (por medio de su id) y lo descarga como un archivo Excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema es que descarga dicho Excel con el fondo completamente en blanco, y si la tabla muestra caracteres con acento, dieresis o `ñ`, los remplaza en lugar de descargar la tabla tal cuál.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación dejo el fragmento de la función en js.

```
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}

// Execute a function when the user presses a key on the keyboard
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  // If the user presses the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    // Cancel the default action, if needed
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger the button element with a click
    document.getElementById("boton1").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Quizás si le das el formato de utf8 o latino antes de enviar al Excel.

Comment: El código produce un archivo con extensión `xls`, pero no se preocupa por generar uno con el formato correcto. Básicamente es una chapuza. Te invito a utilizar alguna librería como [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) o mirar la [especificación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/cd03cb5f-ca02-4934-a391-bb674cb8aa06) y hacer tu propia librería para crear archivos xls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para que Excel reconozca los caracteres acentuados tenes que enviar [**la marca de orden de bytes** o `BOM`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_orden_de_bytes).

Además, actualmente todos los navegadores soportan [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Blob#compatibilidad_con_navegadores), por lo que te propongo modificar tu función `exportTableToExcel` así:

```js
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = '') {
  var tableHTML = document.getElementById(tableID).outerHTML;
  var blob = new Blob([
    new Uint8Array([0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF]), // UTF-8 BOM
    tableHTML
  ], {
    type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
  });

  // Create download link element
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

  // Create a link to the file
  downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  // Specify file name
  filename = filename ? filename + '.xls' : 'excel_data.xls';

  // Setting the file name
  downloadLink.download = filename;

  //triggering the function
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Descargar XLS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="mitabla">
    <tr>
      <td>COMPAÑIA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>FICCIÓN</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="exportTableToExcel('mitabla')">Descargar</button>
</body>

</html>
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvió.